# Wvdial randomly drops 3G connection - How to auto-reconnect?

Tags: 10.04, networking, 3g

I'm using a 3G modem for a router running Ubuntu server 10.04. I have the connection established using wvdial, which works successfully, but sometimes the connection drops. I would like it to auto re-connect.

I've set the "auto reconnect" in wvdial.conf, but this does not seem to work. Any ideas? Am I missing a config option, or should I try writing a script which polls the network status and resets if ppp0 has gone down?

Comment: Ideally you would configure NetworkManager to handle this task, and reconnect when the connection is down.

Comment: I'm not using NetworkManager - this is a server machine, so I need manual control over the interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the *auto reconnect* feature of `wvdial` and provide a wrapper script instead of calling `wvdial` (no need for polling):

```
#! /bin/bash
(
    while : ; do
        wvdial
        sleep 10
    done
) &
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution for mobile broadband autoconnection/ reconnection at http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1456

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Additionally: what works on Mint does not necessarily on Ubuntu too

Comment: This works for Mint of Ubuntu GUI, but not for server without Network Manager command line installed.